# Left join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, left-join

I am using left join to combine two tables. They are `SOP10100` and `SOP10106`.

I have to get two invoices (rows) after combining two tables. Now I am getting four invoices (rows).

Can you look my query and point out where I am making mistake(s)?

```
Select
    DISTINCT DETAIL.SOPNUMBE as Invoice,
    DETAIL.DOCDATE as Date,
    DETAIL.CUSTNMBR as 'Customer Id',
    DETAIL.CUSTNAME as Customer_Name,
    DETAIL.SUBTOTAL as Sub_Total,
    DETAIL.FRTAMNT as Freight,
    DETAIL.TAXAMNT as Tax,
    DETAIL.DOCAMNT AS 'Doc_Amount',
    CASE when USRDEF05 <> ' ' THEN USRDEF05 ELSE '0'END as Winsys
FROM SOP10100 DETAIL 
Left JOIN SOP10106 USERDEF
ON USERDEF.soptype = DETAIL.soptype
WHERE BACHNUMB ='WINSYS112012'
```

[image]

Comment: I did not get any error. But my output getting duplicate values.can you please look at my screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

`soptype` in the invoice table matches two records in the`userdef` table. You'll see that for each invoice, you have two different `Winsys`. Which one do you want to associate with your invoice? The answer to that question must be incorporated into the logic of your query.

You may want `MAX(Winsys)` for instance (in your case, `MAX(CASE ... END) as Winsys`). As long as you have not specified how you want to aggregate values when more than one record in the left join matches the table you're selecting from, you're going to receive all combinations.

When you've come up with the proper aggregate, you'll also need to `GROUP BY` the fields you're selecting from your invoice table.

It may be an error that there are two records in `SOP10106` that have the same `soptype`. If that is the case, simply correct that, and you will not have duplicates.